# Can we refer static resources in List View Button Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i made a list button for a custom object.In this button when on click i have to run javascript.i have to include jQuery in my page.can anyone please tell is it possible to refer it using $Resource.Bootstrap or i have to use a cdn url for referring to it.i read some where its better to include these jquery and bootstrap file from static resource for performance reason.please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this: Below reference is useful. will try it..
http://jevonearth.blogspot.com/2011/08/using-static-resources-with-salesforce.html